# How to cross compile a Go program for an ARM device passing it a custom dynamic C library to link against?

Tags: go, arm, cross-compiling, dynamic-linking

I am facing difficulties while attempting to cross compile a Go program for an ARM device that involves NFC communication. The code I am working with is essentially the same as the one provided in this GitHub [repository](https://github.com/xBlaz3kx/nfc-reader-example).

However, I encounter the following error during the compilation process:

```
# runtime/cgo
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lnfc: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To provide some context, I have the ARM binary for libnfc located in the same folder as my project. When I execute the ls -lha command, the output is as follows:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4.0K Jun 22 08:29 .
drwxrwxr-x 14 user user 4.0K Jun 22 08:04 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user user  194 Jun 22 08:30 build.sh
drwxrwxr-x  8 user user 4.0K Jun 22 08:02 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user  103 Jun 22 08:04 go.mod
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user  175 Jun 22 08:04 go.sum
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user  99K Aug  5  2019 libnfc.so.5.0.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user  679 Jun 22 08:08 nfc-reader-example.go
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 1.8K Jun 22 08:02 Readme.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 3.1K Jun 22 08:03 TagReader.go
```

To verify that the correct binary is available, I ran the file command on the libnfc file, and the output confirms it as an ARM binary:

```
libnfc.so.5.0.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=1fc3310eac4e2a16c7de93c60e9a66d0d70f455d, stripped
```

Now, I am attempting to compile the code using the provided build.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CGO_ENABLED=1
export GOOS=linux
export CGO_LDFLAGS="-Xlinker -rpath=./libnfc.so.5 -lnfc"
export GOARCH=arm

go build -ldflags "-s -w"
```

Due to recommendations I tried changging the flag `export CGO_LDFLAGS="-L$(pwd) -lnfc"`and building with the `-x` flag, getting the output:

```
cd /CORRECT_PATH/nfc-reader-example
rm -f nfc-reader-example nfc-reader-example.exe nfc-reader-go-example nfc-reader-go-example.exe nfc-reader-example.test nfc-reader-example.test.exe nfc-reader-go-example.test nfc-reader-go-example.test.exe TagReader TagReader.exe nfc-reader-example nfc-reader-example.exe
WORK=/tmp/go-build244897722
mkdir -p $WORK/b038/
cd /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgo
TERM='dumb' CGO_LDFLAGS='"-L/CORRECT_PATH/nfc-reader-example" "-lnfc" "-lpthread"' /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cgo -objdir $WORK/b038/ -importpath runtime/cgo -import_runtime_cgo=false -import_syscall=false -- -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror ./cgo.go
cd $WORK
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -fno-caret-diagnostics -c -x c - -o /dev/null || true
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Qunused-arguments -c -x c - -o /dev/null || true
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -fdebug-prefix-map=a=b -c -x c - -o /dev/null || true
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -gno-record-gcc-switches -c -x c - -o /dev/null || true
cd $WORK/b038
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgo -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I ./ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o ./_x001.o -c _cgo_export.c
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgo -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I ./ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o ./_x002.o -c cgo.cgo2.c
cd /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgo
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I . -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o $WORK/b038/_x003.o -c gcc_context.c
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I . -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o $WORK/b038/_x004.o -c gcc_fatalf.c
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I . -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o $WORK/b038/_x005.o -c gcc_libinit.c
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I . -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o $WORK/b038/_x006.o -c gcc_linux_arm.c
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I . -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o $WORK/b038/_x007.o -c gcc_setenv.c
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I . -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o $WORK/b038/_x008.o -c gcc_traceback.c
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I . -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o $WORK/b038/_x009.o -c gcc_util.c
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I . -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o $WORK/b038/_x010.o -c linux_syscall.c
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I . -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I $WORK/b038/ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o $WORK/b038/_x011.o -c gcc_arm.S
cd $WORK/b038
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgo -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I ./ -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -o ./_cgo_main.o -c _cgo_main.c
cd /CORRECT_PATH/nfc-reader-example
TERM='dumb' arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgo -fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b038=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -o $WORK/b038/_cgo_.o $WORK/b038/_cgo_main.o $WORK/b038/_x001.o $WORK/b038/_x002.o $WORK/b038/_x003.o $WORK/b038/_x004.o $WORK/b038/_x005.o $WORK/b038/_x006.o $WORK/b038/_x007.o $WORK/b038/_x008.o $WORK/b038/_x009.o $WORK/b038/_x010.o $WORK/b038/_x011.o -L/CORRECT_PATH/nfc-reader-example -lnfc -lpthread -pie
# runtime/cgo
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: não foi possível localizar -lnfc: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I would theorize that `ld` cannot find your library because the current directory is not in its search path (which is modified via the `-L` command-line parameter for `cc` (and `gcc` for that matter)). Also your `-rpath` appears to be incorrect for two reasons: it should be `--rpath`, and it should specify a directory. Still, I'd try not to play with `-Xlinker` and just use `-L` as usual.

Comment: I tried doing it either with only the `CGO_LDFLAGS="-L. -lnfc"` or also adding  the `CGO_CFLAGS="-I."`, but neither worked

Comment: That `.` might easily resolve into not what you expect it to be. Can you add the `-x` command-line option to your `go build` call and see how it builds (and where, and how does it call all the commands)? I'd recommend to first delete all intermediate files–i.e., to have a clean build. I mean, `go build` does create a temporray directory when building, and I'd not be surprised if it `cd`s there for some reason`.

Comment: Using `export CGO_LDFLAGS="-L$(pwd) -lnfc"` and building with the `-x` flag it goes to the correct directory and tries to build, I'm going to add the output in the question.

Comment: Can you create a symlink named `libnfc.so` pointing at `libnfc.so.5.0.1` and try again?

Comment: That was it, the name in the link `-lnfc` looks for a file `libnfc.so`, by creating the link I solved that, thank you.

Comment: Cool. So, does it work if you return back `-L.`? ;-)